# Html calendar on load doesn't return the dates values for landing month

Tags: javascript, jquery

Still trying to get hold of JQuery. Not really good at it.

I have a problem with HTML calendar. Everything on this calendar works perfect except for loading the calendar first time "Landing month doesn't return the values for dates occupied."

If after load I select other months I can see the dates occupied and even after re-selecting the landing month (First dropdownlist) dates can be seen there but just not on first load.

Here is the code:

```
    var cal = new Calendar();

    var unavailable_days_month_1 = [1,2,3];
    var unavailable_days_month_2 = [4,5,6];
    var unavailable_days_month_3 = [7,8,9];
    var unavailable_days_month_4 = [10,11,12];
    var unavailable_days_month_5 = [13,14,15];
    var unavailable_days_month_6 = [16,17,18];
    var unavailable_days_month_7 = [19,20,21];
    var unavailable_days_month_8 = [22,23,24];
    var unavailable_days_month_9 = [25,26,27];
    var unavailable_days_month_10 = [28,29,30];
    var unavailable_days_month_11 = [2,4,31];
    var unavailable_days_month_12 = [7,9,11];

    var current_date = new Date();
    var current_month = (current_date.getMonth() + 1);
    var current_year_month = (1900 + current_date.getYear()) + "-" + current_month;
    tjq("#select-month").find("[value='" + current_year_month + "']").prop("selected", "selected");
    /* My problem starts from here. How can I return the dates value for landing calender month */
    cal.generateHTML(current_date.getMonth(), (1900 + current_date.getYear()), "unavailable_days_month_" + current_month);
    tjq(".calendar").html(cal.getHTML());

    tjq("#select-month").change(function() {
        var selected_year_month = tjq("#select-month option:selected").val();
        var year = parseInt(selected_year_month.split("-")[0], 10);
        var month = parseInt(selected_year_month.split("-")[1], 10);
        cal.generateHTML(month - 1, year, getUnavailDays(month));
        tjq(".calendar").html(cal.getHTML());
    });

        function getUnavailDays(month){
           if (month === 1) return unavailable_days_month_1;
           if (month === 1) return unavailable_days_month_1;
           if (month === 2) return unavailable_days_month_2;
           if (month === 3) return unavailable_days_month_3;
           if (month === 4) return unavailable_days_month_4;
           if (month === 5) return unavailable_days_month_5;
           if (month === 6) return unavailable_days_month_6;
           if (month === 7) return unavailable_days_month_7;
           if (month === 8) return unavailable_days_month_8;
           if (month === 9) return unavailable_days_month_9;
           if (month === 10) return unavailable_days_month_10;
           if (month === 11) return unavailable_days_month_11;
           if (month === 12) return unavailable_days_month_12;

           return;
        }
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should begin by refactoring your code. Consider creating an array called unavailable_days_month where the index is the month number.

Answer (score 0):

I had to made these changes:

```
var current_date = new Date();
var current_month = (current_date.getMonth() + 1);
var current_year_month = (1900 + current_date.getYear()) + "-" + (current_date.getMonth() + 1);
tjq("#select-month").find("[value='" + current_year_month + "']").prop("selected", "selected");
cal.generateHTML(current_date.getMonth(), (1900 + current_date.getYear()), getCurrMonth(current_month));
tjq(".calendar").html(cal.getHTML());

function getCurrMonth(current_month){
   if (current_month === 1) return unavailable_days_month_1;
   if (current_month === 2) return unavailable_days_month_2;
   if (current_month === 3) return unavailable_days_month_3;
   if (current_month === 4) return unavailable_days_month_4;
   if (current_month === 5) return unavailable_days_month_5;
   if (current_month === 6) return unavailable_days_month_6;
   if (current_month === 7) return unavailable_days_month_7;
   if (current_month === 8) return unavailable_days_month_8;
   if (current_month === 9) return unavailable_days_month_9;
   if (current_month === 10) return unavailable_days_month_10;
   if (current_month === 11) return unavailable_days_month_11;
   if (current_month === 12) return unavailable_days_month_12;

   return;
}
```